# adb shell on my phone device: weird characters appear (terminal color issue)

Tags: android, adb

I have a Samsung Galaxy S with DarkyRom 10.4.2 XWJW1 (Android 2.3.6) and root access. I'm implementing an application and I wanted to execute it in my phone using eclipse, but I get the error: ActivityManager: /sbin/sh: am: not found. I tried to use adb shell to see what's going on, and if I use ls I get:

```
<-[1;34macct<-[0m
<-[1;34mcache<-[0m
<-[1;34mconfig<-[0m
...
```

I read here in stackoverflow that the am error could be because of a missing line in am file. I used busybox vi am and this is what I get:

```
<-999;999H<-[6n<-[1;1H<-[J
~
~
~
...
~
~<-[1;1H<-[24;1H<-[K- am 1/1 100%<-[1;1H
```

Does someone know why these weird characters appear? How can I fix it?

EDIT: 
Googling a bit more I found that this is a color issue. If I use 'ls --color=none' I don't see the weird characters anymore, Windows terminal doesn't support color. But I still want to edit the am file and the --color=none doesn't work with the vi command. What is the command to disable color in 'busybox vi am'?

Answer (score 0):

As you've said, the problem is that windows console doesn't support the linux console color technique.
A solution will be to use putty with adb support. Information can be found here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803225