# The adb shell screen is strange

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am using the iot module of a Chinese company called ingenic. And I use it in Korea.

However, if you access the module with adb shell command, the directory name looks strange like the screen below. Do you know why? This is too uncomfortable.

> [1;34mVIOMI_Ment[0m  [1;34mfirmware[0m    [1;34mmedia[0m
>   [1;34mroot[0m        [1;34mtestsuite[0m [1;34mbin[0m
>   [1;34mlib[0m         [1;34mmnt[0m         [1;34mrun[0m
>   [1;34mtmp[0m [1;34mdev[0m         [1;36mlib32[0m
>   [1;34mopt[0m         [1;34msbin[0m        [1;34musr[0m
>   [1;34metc[0m         [1;36mlinuxrc[0m     [1;34mproc[0m
>   [1;34msys[0m         [1;34mvar[0m

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11429520/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38617204

Answer (score 2):

The shell/terminal on your host PC does not support [ANSI Escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Escape_sequences) for color and your Android device has color enabled in its console. So you need to either start using capable terminal or disable color in your device's console.

Comment: Specifically, I do not know what to do. What should I do?

Comment: my answer is as specific as your question allows. you did not provide any relevant specifics about your environment

Comment: also your posting contains the only question - *Do you know why?* which was exactly what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use windows CMD to control adb command?
If in CMD , it maybe the ANSI to UTF-8 question.

1.chcp (show your Active code page)

2.chcp 65001 (change your Active code page to UTF-8)

3.CMD settings to change your front like the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMsTj.png)

Comment: Should I add the lucida font separately?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your console does not support ANSI color escape sequences. If you are using Windows 10, you can now enable ANSI color support:

- Open Windows PowerShell as administrator
- Run command `Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Console VirtualTerminalLevel -Type DWORD 1`

  - This will enable ANSI escape sequences by default in Windows Console (cmd, PowerShell)

Now when you run `adb shell`, you should see colors instead of those color codes.

More info on https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling