# Messy output on screen when running ncurses native android app from windows host

Tags: android, windows, adb, ncurses

I am running an native ncurses statically build application for Ubuntu on Android device. I am getting the expected screen output on Ubuntu.

I pushed the ncurses executable onto Android device which is connected to Windows host machine using adb.

When I tried to run the application on android device, messy output on windows dos terminal is coming.
I copied the terminfo onto Android device set TERMINFO and set TERM=xterm.

What am I missing?

Comment: Windows doesn't use xterm. If you're using Windows 10 you can enable support for ANSI escape sequences in console windows, which maybe close enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52323858/1778421